# I2C protocol between PIC32mx and Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, pic, i2c, microchip

I am implementing a way to transfer data using I2C protocol between PIC32mx and Arduino Uno. I've decided to establish **PIC** as **master** and **Arduino** as **slave**. I passed by all the definitions and configs for the I2C in the PIC because I already have it working perfectly with a barometer. Let's consider the Arduino as one more slave in this protocol. 
So from the PIC master-side I have the following code

```
#define EEPROM_I2C_BUS              I2C1
#define i2d_address                 0x14
#define I2C_CLOCK_FREQ              5000


BOOL BarI2CTransmitOneByte( UINT8 data )
{
// Wait for the transmitter to be ready
while(G_RUNNING && !I2CTransmitterIsReady(EEPROM_I2C_BUS));

// Transmit the byte
if(I2CSendByte(EEPROM_I2C_BUS, data) == I2C_MASTER_BUS_COLLISION)
{
    DBPRINTF("Error: I2C Master Bus Collision\n");
    return FALSE;
}
// Wait for the transmission to finish
while(G_RUNNING && !I2CTransmissionHasCompleted(EEPROM_I2C_BUS));

return TRUE;
}

void BarI2CStopTransfer( void )
{
I2C_STATUS  status;

// Send the Stop signal
I2CStop(EEPROM_I2C_BUS);

// Wait for the signal to complete
do
{
    status = I2CGetStatus(EEPROM_I2C_BUS);

} while( G_RUNNING && !(status & I2C_STOP) );
}


BOOL BarI2CStartTransfer( BOOL restart )
{
I2C_STATUS  status;

//    // Send the Stop signal
// I2CStop(EEPROM_I2C_BUS);

// Send the Start (or Restart) signal
if(restart)
{
    I2CRepeatStart(EEPROM_I2C_BUS);
}
else
{
    // Wait for the bus to be idle, then start the transfer
    while( G_RUNNING && !I2CBusIsIdle(EEPROM_I2C_BUS) );

    if(I2CStart(EEPROM_I2C_BUS) != I2C_SUCCESS)
    {
        DBPRINTF("Error: Bus collision during transfer Start\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
}
// Wait for the signal to complete
do
{
    status = I2CGetStatus(EEPROM_I2C_BUS);

} while ( !(status & I2C_START) );

return TRUE;
} 


void main(){
UINT32              actualClock;
BOOL                Success2 = TRUE;

actualClock = I2CSetFrequency(EEPROM_I2C_BUS, GetPeripheralClock(), I2C_CLOCK_FREQ);
if ( abs(actualClock-I2C_CLOCK_FREQ) > I2C_CLOCK_FREQ/10 )
{
   //DBPRINTF("Error: I2C1 clock frequency (%u) error exceeds 10%%.\n", (unsigned)actualClock);
}
// Enable the I2C bus
I2CEnable(EEPROM_I2C_BUS, TRUE);


I2C_FORMAT_7_BIT_ADDRESS(SlaveAddress,  i2d_address, I2C_WRITE);
i2cData[0] = SlaveAddress.byte;
i2cData[1] = 0x03;         // EEPROM location to read (high address byte)
DataSz = 2;


if( !BarI2CStartTransfer(FALSE) )
{
    while(G_RUNNING && 1);
}

Index = 0;
while(Success2 & (Index < DataSz) )
{
    // Transmit a byte
    if (BarI2CTransmitOneByte(i2cData[Index]))
    {
        // Advance to the next byte
        Index++;
    }
    else
    {
        Success2 = FALSE;
    }

    // Verify that the byte was acknowledged
    if(!I2CByteWasAcknowledged(EEPROM_I2C_BUS))
    {
        DBPRINTF("Error: Sent byte was not acknowledged\n");
        Success2 = FALSE;
    }
}

BarI2CStopTransfer();

if(Success2)
{
    // Send a Repeated Started condition
    if( !BarI2CStartTransfer(FALSE) )
    {
        while(1);
    }

    // Transmit the address with the READ bit set
    I2C_FORMAT_7_BIT_ADDRESS(SlaveAddress,  i2d_address, I2C_READ);
    if (BarI2CTransmitOneByte(SlaveAddress.byte))
    {
        // Verify that the byte was acknowledged
        if(!I2CByteWasAcknowledged(EEPROM_I2C_BUS))
        {
            DBPRINTF("Error: Sent byte was not acknowledged\n");
            Success2 = FALSE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Success2 = FALSE;
    }
}
// Read the data from the desired address
if(Success2)
{
    if(I2CReceiverEnable(EEPROM_I2C_BUS, TRUE) == I2C_RECEIVE_OVERFLOW)
    {
        DBPRINTF("Error: I2C Receive Overflow\n");
        Success2 = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        while(!I2CReceivedDataIsAvailable(EEPROM_I2C_BUS));
        i2cbyte = I2CGetByte(EEPROM_I2C_BUS);
    }
}
BarI2CStopTransfer();
if(!Success2)
{
    while( G_RUNNING && 1);
}
```

For the **Arduino** slave-side I wrote this following code:

```
void setup(void) 
{
Wire.begin(20);
Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
Serial.begin(9600); // start serial comm
}

void receiveEvent(int howMany){
int x = Wire.read();   
}

void requestEvent(){
Wire.write('x');
}

void loop(){
}
```

So from the PIC side I am sending the byte 0x03 which I receive in the **receiveEvent** method in the Arduino side. At this point everything is working well. After that the **requestEvent** is called and the 'x' character is beeing sent to the PIC side. Now the PIC side is blocking in the `DBPRINTF("Error: I2C Receive Overflow\n");` sentence which means I am taking too long to receive the 'x' byte from the Arduino side and the SDA line is never released as well.

I have pull ups in my I2C protocol at 3.3V (**Master-PIC**) and I trying to communicate using the `A4(SDA)` and `A5(SCL)` in the **Slave-Arduino** side which is at 5V.
I am following this [Tutorial](http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/i2c-tutorial) carefully and trying to replicate the "Reading from a slave" part but without success.

EDIT: I am following the procedure and I am receiving the byte properly from the arduino side however the code is locked up in the `RFIDI2CStopTransfer();` in the PIC side and I don't know why. Is there someone who can help me with this issue?

Comment: Your code fragments are a little too incomplete in my opinion. You haven't shown any of the master functions like BarI2CTransmitOneByte() and BarI2CStartTransfer(). Also you haven't shown a scope or logic analyzer capture showing that the traffic is what you expect. Also it appears that you're using the same function to send start and restart (BarI2CStartTransfer) - in PIC32 (much like PIC24) start and restart are separate bits in the I2CxCON register (SEN and RSEN respectively). Please add some more meat to this question.

Comment: I already updated my post with the functions you asked me for. Please take a look, I am not using the same function to start and restart transfer. Unfortunately I don't have a logic analyzer here @AdamLawrence

Comment: @scuba ditch the Serial.print() in requestEvent. It'll take about 13ms seconds to print that string--too long. Did u try my earlier recommendation?

Comment: @TisteAndii yes Sir and no results. Already removed the Serial.print() in requestEvent and no results as well. I am trying to follow this (http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/i2c-tutorialtutorial) and it seems my code is doing it perfectly. I have no more ideas.

Comment: Your link is broken. By recommendation, i meant the PIC32 sample code whose pastebin link i sent to u in the chatroom. Also in your present code, it looks like you're defining functions within main()

Comment: there was an error in the copy-paste http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/i2c-tutorial. Like the main code. I am fixing it.

Comment: With the code you suggest the I cannot go beyond the start Transfer method. I checked with a breakpoint.

Comment: @scuba the receiver overflow error occurs because data was received while there was unread data in the rx buffer. Try calling GetByte before you enable the receiver. Also try editing the code here: http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/PIC32/PLIB_examples/plib_examples/i2c/i2c_master/source/i2c_master.c; its clearer and has been tested given its source.

Comment: It seems Arduino is forcing the line to logic value 1 and it never goes down by the end at the last StopTransfer(). I believe the problem is in the Arduino side, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38047/discussion-between-tisteandii-and-scuba).

Comment: I followed your discussion with Majenko. Have you tried my PIC32 code with his suggestions about the address? Any improvements at all? Or does it halt at the same point?

Comment: @TisteAndii it's solved. I was using the slave number 7 and it seems its reserved, So i changed to 20 and now it's working perfectly.

Comment: @scuba Great. You might want to post an answer here and in Arduino.SE.

Comment: @TisteAndii can you please look at the Edit I have made?

Comment: Did you remove the Serial.print()s in requestEvent? Update the code in your question, if you've made any changes. Does it begin StopTransfer() at all or does it get stuck in the while loop before it? And what exactly is G_RUNNING?

Comment: Already updated the code. I've removed the Serial.print()s and the problem is in the side of the PIC32. It's stucked in the StopTransfer, inside the do{ }while loop.

Comment: Perhaps its because you arent NACKing. Add `I2CAcknowledgeByte(EEPROM_I2C_BUS, FALSE); while (!I2CAcknowledgeHasCompleted(EEPROM_I2C_BUS));` after `I2CGetByte()` and try again. If it gets stuck, where does it get stuck this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some part of the the issue was related with the address I've use to communicate with the Arduino. I was using 0x07 as an address but it is reserved so I changed to 0x14 (20 in decimal). However I've edited the post in order to get some help with this new issue.